# Why is the Unreal Engine transform widget not aligned to my exported mesh?

Tags: export, unreal-engine

Exporting my mesh from blender to unreal - just a simple wall - the unreal transform widget (scale, move, rotate) is not aligned with the mesh in UE4 and instead the widget is way in front of the mesh. I can obviously just snap the widget pivot point to the mesh, but I have to that every time I move it. What do I have to do so my imported models have the widget aligned with the mesh from the start so I can align it easier.

Comment: When you export, the mesh must be at the Origo. Hit Alt+G before exporting.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought i did have it at the world origin but it wasn't exactly there. Just the front edge was sitting at the origin, i had to set origin to geometry then selection to cursor. Once again thank you for clearing that up for me, still learning blender. I'm only like a month into blender lol.